# PHP - Find difference in 2 strings and get path to difference

Tags: php, xpath

I got 2 html files which use same template only some fields different and i need to get full xpath to those differences using PHP.

1st)

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="price">12,400</div>
<div class="make">Acura</div>
```

2nd)

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="price">15,400</div>
<div class="make">Bmw</div>
```

So as you can see from example its the same template but price is different and make 
So PHP script suppose to show xpath (those results):

```
//div[@class='price']
//div[@class='make']
```

Script needs to find difference in 2 files and get xpath to that difference, obviously template is unknown and every time could be different

Any Help Appreciated!!!

Comment: The best what i found is script which highlight the difference in two files, but i couldnt convert it to those needs, i was looking the way to get xpath of specific html element thru php and same got stuck

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

First get the content of the files (file_get_content), then explode them to arrays.

Use array diff to see the difference.

```
$content1 = '<html>
<body>
<div class="price">12,400</div>
<div class="make">Acura</div>';

$content2 = '<html>
<body>
<div class="price">15,400</div>
<div class="make">Bmw</div>';

$arr1 = explode("\n", $content1);
$arr2 = explode("\n", $content2);

Var_dump(array_diff($arr1,$arr2));
```

Comment: No not on it's own. But I guess it could if absolutely needed.

Comment: so after a while of research it looks like its almost unreal to get xpath from difference in files , so what can we load files into Dom and then somehow create array of all nodes and then compare content of those nodes ?

Comment: Is there any way to get this kind of array from html file  based on DOM Objects ?

1st file)
array( "body" => '"div class="price"' => 12,400
       => '"div class="make"' => Acura
     ) 

2nd file)
array( "body" => '"div class="price"' => 15,400
       => '"div class="make"' => Bmw
     ) 

and then compare both array to see what is different ?

Comment: I have 10000+ templates(sites) , to get values(like price , address and so on) from those sites I decide for every site to compare couple pages and extract only parts that are different , other wise I would have to go thru 10000+ sites and for every site create unique "xpath query" to extract data

Comment: If all pages have similar setups (not to many different tags and styles) then it shouldn't be too hard to convert a normal array to a multidimensional array where each layer is an open tag. The problem will be to match the arrays later because div1 -> p -> img is not the same as div2 -> img even if it's the same image. So what needs to be done is probably to match from each inner most item and still looking at the address behind to see if it's a match. It does sound complicated and probably will be. What is the real purpose of this? I think Ms Word have some feature for this.